# Getting width of image (by URL) outside function w/ JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, function, variables, width

I'm trying to get the width of two images based on their URLs (so, actual image size).  I'm able to do that in such a way so as to pop up an alert based on the results, but anything outside of the actual function results in an undefined value for the widths of the two images.

```
var w1 = "";
var w2 = "";
var img1 = new Image();
img1.onload = function() { w1 = this.width;};
img1.src = "URL1";

var img2 = new Image();
img2.onload = function() { w2 = this.width;};
img2.src = "URL2";

alert (w1 + " and " + w2);
```

How do I use w1 and w2 outside of the functions that set them to this.width?

Ideally I'd like to compare them and later on use the larger one.  But I can't even get them to show with their correct values in the alert (above).

Thanks in advance!

Adendum:

```
var img1 = new Image(); 
var img2 = new Image();
var one, two;
img1.src = "img1.jpg";  
img2.src = "img2.jpg";
img1.onload = function() {img2.onload = function() {compareWidth(img1.width, img2.width);}}

var finalchoice;
var compareWidth  = function (width1 ,width2){
if(width1 > width2){
        finalchoice = img1.src;
        alert(finalchoice);
        return finalchoice;
    }
    else{
        finalchoice = img2.src;
        alert(finalchoice);
        return finalchoice;
        }
}
```

Idea being then to use final choice later in the .js file.

Comment: Scratch everything I said :P didn't read fully.  Your issue is that the alert is being called BEFORE the onload events are being processed. setting the url starts the download, and the onload is run when they are done... meanwhile the alert waits for nothing and continues.

Comment: @rlemon but he is declaring the var w1, w2 out side of the function?

Comment: @SumanBogati if you are commenting before my comment edit -> my bad, I didn't fully read his code properly.

Comment: @RyanNorman you need to preload all of your images, and when they are done you can compare the widths of any of them. I have a blog post about doing this, but my blogger is down :/ I will update if I can get back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `alert (w1 + " and " + w2);` 
statment is executed before the image is loaded that's why the result is displaying undefined.

To compare the width of two images you can use this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
var img1 = new Image(); 
img1.src = "w3javascript.gif";  
img1.onload = function() { 
    document.body.appendChild(img1); //this is optional you can remove it
    compareWidth(this.width);
}

var img2 = new Image(); 
img2.src = "author.jpg";  
img2.onload = function() { 
    document.body.appendChild(img2); //this is optional you can remove it
    compareWidth(this.width);
}

var w1;
var compareWidth  = function (width){
    //here you can do operation with width and height
    if(typeof w1 == 'undefined'){
        w1 = width;
    }else{
        if(w1 < width){
            alert('do one thing');
        }else{
            alert('do other thing');
        }
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: So will this allow me to compare the width of img1 and img2 to each other?  It looks like it'll only run the compareWidth function once for each img as it is called.

Comment: Yeah, you will have to call compareWidth() function twice as illustrated into the code, infact above code is comparing the width of two images, please place your images over the 'w3javascript.gif' and "author.jpg" respectively.

Comment: I did that.  The thing that I think is happening with this is that for the first image I call compareWidth, it compares it to something (not the second image).  Then, I call it again for the second image where it does the same.  I tried it twice with a larger image for 1 and then for 2 and I get the same result... "do other thing".

Comment: Something like my addendum above... though that isn't working either.

Comment: As I said, if you place the two different size images in above code and run this code, there will be either excuted `alert('do one thing');`  or excuted `alert('do other thing');`, you can do your job in different condition (if, else), hope this helps to you.

Comment: I tried it again.  It worked perfectly!  Thanks!  I'm not sure why it didn't work the first time.  Typo on my part I'm sure!

Answer (score -3):

i would recommend using jQuery...

Just load jQuery ... > like `<script src="{jquery-lib-path}"></script>`

and do something like

```
var imgWidth = img.width():
```

Comment: It isn't a good idea to suggest loading a bloated library JUST for one function - Rather if this is your only idea isolate the code within jQuery doing this and offer that. Also this question appears to be about function scope and not getting the actual widths.